# AutoEncoders not showing the expected output in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I'm experimenting with AutoEncoders in Keras . where I have a data set (network intrusion NLS-DATASET) that I want my auto encoder to learn its identity and be able to reconstruct the input.

but it appears that the auto encoder is generating an output way off the input.

my AutoEncoder code looks like this:

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
input_event= Input(shape=(37,))
# encoded and decoded layer for the autoencoder
encoded = Dense(units=35, activation='linear')(input_event)
encoded = Dense(units=30 ,activation='linear')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(units=25 ,activation='linear')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(units=15, activation='linear')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(units=25, activation='linear')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(units=30, activation='linear')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(units=35, activation='linear')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(units=37, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)

# Building autoencoder
autoencoder=Model(input_event, decoded)
# compiling the autoencoder
#binary_crossentropy
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fitting the noise trained data to the autoencoder 
autoencoder.fit(train_preprocessed, train_preprocessed,
                epochs=500,
                batch_size=500,
                shuffle=True
                )
```

the input looks like this :

```
array([  1.44929445e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         1.95694716e-03,   1.95694716e-03,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         5.25490196e-01,   3.37254902e-01,   6.10000000e-01,
         4.00000000e-02,   6.10000000e-01,   2.00000000e-02,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00])
```

and the reconstructed input of the same sample looks like this :

```
array([  2.74842819e-06,   1.79134950e-05,   2.46820991e-06,
         1.92149782e-05,   1.90284572e-06,   8.65007848e-07,
         9.06300829e-06,   5.82939938e-05,   2.86187715e-05,
         7.64128927e-04,   1.39977574e-05,   2.23619267e-04,
         2.37729073e-05,   2.88849260e-05,   7.43528290e-07,
         3.19817104e-06,   1.04340703e-04,   5.09360158e-11,
         2.53149103e-02,   4.43180241e-02,   3.23981070e-03,
         6.98099006e-03,   1.20416423e-03,   2.04246654e-03,
         9.92004931e-01,   8.45971797e-03,   2.18889210e-02,
         5.33952713e-01,   2.81162173e-01,   6.86491251e-01,
         3.13708745e-02,   6.79274261e-01,   4.15302813e-03,
         2.21803953e-06,   9.70323163e-04,   3.18228710e-03,
         1.31858699e-03], dtype=float32)
```

I have tried using different activation functions between the layers , I tried different layer depths . Different loss functions .

I would appreciate your help if you can spot any thing wrong that i'm doing .

thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using other activation functions instead of linear?

Comment: You can use ReLU function in all the layers except the last layer. The last layer must have a linear function.

Comment: @kvish I have tried the following configurations : All layers are Sigmoid, i have tried all Layers to be Relu , I have also tried all hidden are relus and output layer to be linear .

Comment: @Shubham i have tried the configurations that you have mentioned

Comment: @mousaalsulaimi have you tried your last decoder layer to be sigmoid activation and all other to be relu? And also, maybe experiment with a smaller batch size?

Comment: @Kvish yes i have tried all hidden layers to be Relus and the output layer to be a sigmoid but still not able to get an accurate output. i have yet to try different batch sizes

Comment: @mousaalsulaimi that would be good. Also it might be good to start with a simpler architecture in terms of number of layers for encoder and decoder, and then build up. Have you tried with 2 layers?

Comment: @Kvish I just wanted to updated you ,  I have tried both smaller batch size (100 samples ) and smaller networks (2 layers) as you  suggested but still I get the same result. This is very strange. At first i thought that there is a bug that i could not see in my code. but now it appears that it is somthing else.

Comment: @mousaalsulaimi your performance does not seem fundamentally bad so to speak by looking at your example input and reconstructed output, given the loss is mean squared error and the non zero data of your reconstructed output seems to approach your input in most places. I would think you only need more tweaking of your hyperparameters to get a more reasonable result depending on your data!

Comment: @kvish , I will look at the hyperparameters and will experimnt with the a bit more . thank  you for all the advices and help , it is much appreciated.

Comment: @kvish , thank you for your help , i think you were right , the issue was mostly to hyper parameter tuning , additionally i have to perform additional data preprocessing.

Comment: @mousaalsulaimi that's fantastic! You're welcome :)